# How to parse the data special characters are not coming

Tags: jquery, json, special-characters

[image]

I have a table like shown above when i try to access it through ajax i am getting this response.
[image]

why **? " '** characters are not coming..?

Here is my code:

```
var getContact = JSON.parse(temp_ques);
 for (var j = 1; j <= ans_option_count; j++) {
    var temp_var = "sr_no" + j;
    var Option = getContact['option'][temp_var];
    var full_div = '<p><input type="radio" name="ans_option" value="' + j + '" id="optionId' + j + '"  class="validate[required] " /><label for="optionId' + j + '">' + Option + '</label></p>';
    $("#all_option").append(full_div);
    console.log(Option); 
}
```

Comment: Where is this table stored?

Comment: Since <? php ?> is being used for `php` code, you can't do it as simple as that.

Solution is to split the `special-characters` and wrap them with `span` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var getContact = JSON.parse(temp_ques);
 for (var j = 1; j <= ans_option_count; j++) {
    var temp_var = "sr_no" + j;
    var Option = getContact['option'][temp_var];
    
    var sep = ["\\?", '\\"', "\\'"];

    var newOption = "";
    for(var i in sep){
      var regExp = new RegExp(sep[i], 'g');
      var s = sep[i].replace('\\', '');
      newOption = Option.replace(regExp, '<span>' + s + '</span>');
    }
    
    var full_div = '<p><input type="radio" name="ans_option" value="' + j + '" id="optionId' + j + '"  class="validate[required] " /><label for="optionId' + j + '">' + newOption + '</label></p>';
    $("#all_option").append(full_div);
    console.log(newOption); 
}
```

Since `<? php ?>` is being used for php code, you can't do it as simple as that.

Solution is to split the `special-characters` and wrap them with `span` tag.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i cant see any `var i in sep` in `var sep = ["\\?", '\\"', "\\'"];`

Comment: @AbdulWaheed . I've updated the answer. By mistake I was referring to data instead of Option. Have a look into the solution (last line of inner for loop)

Comment: still it is not coming. im getting single quotations i dont know why in data base there are no single quotations, what is i in for loop you written.? should i keep the same or J @Shiladitya

Comment: @AbdulWaheed . That `i` loop is for spliting the `special-characters` from the string & wrapping them with `span` tag.

Comment: Actualy <?php ?> is not coming into the option. may be issue is while parsing.

Comment: Can you share an jsfiddle?